# can't make vm run in emacs > 25;

Tags: emacs26

My life depends on the vm email reader in emacs, and I'm currently using vm 8.2.0b under emacs 25.2.2. When trying to upgrade emacs, I run into problems.

In emacs 26.3, I get the message "Symbol's function definition is void, defun*" -- the asterisk after 'defun' is key here, I believe.

Comment: How about putting this somewhere near the top of your `.emacs` / `init.el` file? `(require 'cl)`.  There have been some changes in Emacs 26 to the `cl-` library that could break some functionality that was relied upon in Emacs 25, but perhaps the changes will not affect your use-case.

Comment: Wow, that worked! Many thanks!

Comment: @lawlist: Please consider making that an answer.

Answer (score 2):

`defun*` is an alias for `cl-defun`, which is a macro defined in `cl-macs.el`. Prior to loading a library that uses `defun*`, consider expressly loading the `cl-...` libraries with `(require 'cl)`.  Some important changes were made to the `cl-...` libraries in Emacs 26, which differ from those of Emacs 25.  If the O.P. encounters problems with the `cl-...` libraries that were not present in Emacs 25, then it may be necessary to invest time debugging to track down the relevant changes ....

Comment: For clarity, `(require 'cl-lib)` would load the modern name-spaced `cl-*` things, while `(require 'cl)` will load the older names without the `cl-` prefix.